# Calling the right object for a method within an if statement?

Tags: java

I'm at a loss right now. I have a method, .usePortal() that is supposed to check if a location is null, and if not, then teleport the person to the next connected location. However, I'm stuck on what object to call to make the teleportation part happen.

```
public void usePortal(){
    if(agentLocation != null){
        transport(this);
    }
}
```

Here's the other classes

```
public class Space {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Portal portal;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public Portal getPortal() {
        return this.portal;
    }
    public void setName(String userName){
        this.name = userName ;
    }
    public void setDescription(String userDescription){
        this.description = userDescription;
    }
    public void setPortal(Portal portal){
        this.portal = portal;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
    public String toStringLong() {
        return this.name + ":" +" " + this.description + " with a " + portal.portalToStringLong();
    }
}

class Portal {
    private String portalName;
    private String portalDirection;
    private Space portalDestination;

    public String getName(){
        return this.portalName;
    }
    public String getDirection(){
        return this.portalDirection;
    }

    public Space getDestination(){
        return this.portalDestination;
    }

    public void setName(String portalName){
        this.portalName = portalName;
    }
    public void setDirection(String portalDirection){
        this.portalDirection = portalDirection;
    }
    public void setDestination(Space portalDestination){
        this.portalDestination = portalDestination;
    }


    public String portalToString() {
        return this.portalName + " that goes " + this.portalDirection;
    }
    public String portalToStringLong(){
        return this.portalName + " that goes " + this.portalDirection + " to " + this.portalDestination;
    }

    public void transport(Agent inputAgent) {
        inputAgent.setAgentLocation(this.portalDestination);
    }
}

class Agent{
    private Space agentLocation = null;
    private String agentName;

    public void setAgentLocation(Space classroom){
        agentLocation = classroom;
    }
    public void setAgentName(String name){
        agentName = name;
    }

    public Space getAgentLocation(){
        return this.agentLocation;
    }
    public String getAgentName(){
        return this.agentName;
    }


    public String agentToString(){
        return this.agentName;
    }
    public String agentToStringLong(){
        return this.agentName + " is in " + this.agentLocation;
    }


    public void usePortal(){
        if(agentLocation != null){
            transport(this);
        }

}
class CommandInterpreter{


public static void run(Agent student){



    boolean continueCommand = true;
    while(continueCommand == true){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("==>");
        String userCommand = userInput.next();

        switch(userCommand){
        case "help":
            System.out.println("go, help, look, quit, where");
        case "where":
            student.getAgentLocation().toString();
        case "look":
            student.getAgentLocation().toStringLong();
        //case "go":
            //student.usePortal();
        case "quit":
            continueCommand = false;





        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error? Can you please explain more on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Joshua Ocampo It is hard to answer your question, there are too many uncertainties. I am not sure whether you have restrictions on the method signature and whether there will be multiple `Space` objects. What is the original requirement? If what you provided is flawed, and we assume it is part of the given template to work on, then we will be going way off.

Comment: You show a lot of code, but you don't really describe the problem you have. Please give more details about your problem.

Comment: @user3437460 as for requirements, the only thing is that I need to keep usePortal() without any arguments. But I'm not sure how I am supposed to call the transport() method within the usePortal() method. There are multiple  space objects, two at the moment, and 6-8 when its hopefully finished.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo Where is `transport()` supposed to be located. Is it a method within `Agent` class?

Comment: @user3437460 its within the Portal class. However, I did just clean it up but putting

'public void usePortal(){
if (agentLocation != null){
 agentLocation.getPortal().transport(this);
}'

and that seemed to get rid of my issues, but when I run the full application, it doesnt send me anything back/terminates randomly

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo This is what I deduced from your codes. If Agent were to use `useProtal()` and `usePortal() without argument` must exist in Agent class, then `Agent` class should include another property known `prvate Portal portal`. However it will make more sense if `usePortal()` can accept argument like `userPortal(Portal p)` so that every agent can choose which portal to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to target the right portal and call transport from that object. For instance I imagine something like this:

```
public void usePortal(Portal targetPortal){
    if(agentLocation != null){
        targetPortal.transport(this);
    }
}
```

I assume this is what you want if you have more than one portal, now you will have to find some way to input the right portal into the usePortal method, but if this is a game I will assume you select the portal or the portal that is closest to the Agent perhaps should be selected as the targetPortal.

Perhaps though, what you want is to access the same portal that exist in the space your agent is in, that would be easily done in a similar fashion:

```
public void usePortal(){
    if(agentLocation != null){
        agentLocation.getPortal().transport(this);
    }
}
```

Perhaps you would like to check for null value on agentLocation.getPortal() != null too before you try calling the transport method.

For your latest issue regarding nullPointer when typing out the space object:

```
public String toStringLong() {
    return this.name + ":" +" " + this.description + " with a " + portal.portalToStringLong();
}
```

Inside this you should rewrite it to check if there is a portal before trying to use the portals portalToStringLong() method:

```
public String toStringLong() {
    String portalString = " without a portal.";
    if(portal != null)
        portalString = " with a " + portal.portalToStringLong();
    return this.name + ":" +" " + this.description + portalString;
}
```

Comment: I implimented this bottom one, and it seemed to work, I no longer have errors. However, thhe code is terminating itself without anything being done, even though I have it running in a loop.

Comment: In order to help you with that I would have to see your loop code, specially the part that makes the agent activate the usePortal() method in the first place.

Comment: I just made an edit, it should be at the bottom of the code in the OP

Comment: The answer from @user3437460 is your solution to the loop issue.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo I've added a solution example for the string output.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

> it doesnt send me anything back/terminates randomly

There is no break in your switch statement, hence it will only prompt user once and flow all the way to `quit` and exit from the loop.

```
  switch(userCommand){
    case "help":
        System.out.println("go, help, look, quit, where");
        break;
    case "where":
        student.getAgentLocation().toString();
        break;
    case "look":
        student.getAgentLocation().toStringLong();
        break;
    case "quit":
        continueCommand = false;
  }
```

> line 35, it says to return the location, description, and the portal. But after giving it a room with no portal, it gives an error and then terminates. Is there a way to use something similar to overload and use a return for when I dont have a portal available?

In your `Space` class:

You can do a check for the existence of portal first:

```
public String toStringLong() {
    String descPortal = "Empty portal";
    if(portal != null)
        descPortal = portal.portalToStringLong();
    return this.name + ": " + this.description + " with a " + descPotal;
}
```

Comment: @Joshua Ocampo You will need a `break` for each case.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo If all problems are solved, you may choose one answer which helped you most and accept it by clicking the hollow looking tick beside the answer. You get 2 reputation points in return.

Comment: one last issue is that in line 35, it says to return the location, description, and the portal. But after giving it a room with no portal, it gives an error and then terminates. Is there a way to use something similar to overload and use a return for when I dont have a portal available?

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo Yes, give me a minute. Adding it to my solution.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo Take a look at my extended solution. Check portal object is not null first. If it is null, you can choose to print what you want. In my example, it will print "Empty portal" if `portal` object is `null`.

Comment: @JoshuaOcampo Refresh this page to see my edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

Call the object on the agent as you can control space from agent object and portal can also be controlled using space variable in agent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which portal to use. Could you introduce Portal as a parameter to usePortal and then just set the agentLocation to the destination of the portal?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new `Portal` object like

`Portal portal = new Portal();`

and then call transport on it,

```
portal.transport(this);
```